# $f$ and $g$ are differentiable on R, $f(0)=g(0)=0$, $g'(0) \neq 0$, which of the following is correct?

Tags: calculus

1. $f/g$ can be extended to a continuous function near 0.
2. $\frac{f-f^3}{2g-g^2}$ can be extended to a continuous function near 0.
3. $f/g$ can be extended to a differentiable function near 0.

My guess is 1,2, applying L'Hospital rule. 3 is not correct for $f=x|x|$,$g=x$ I guess?

Comment: What is the original domain of $\frac fg$? Then only can we talk about an extension. Is it those points where $g$ is non-zero?

Comment: I believe here extension refers to  the properties near 0.

Comment: In that case, both $1,2$ should work from L'Hopital.

Comment: your guess looks right to me.

Comment: 1 is the same as 3.

Comment: Option 3 can't be guaranteed but 1 and 2 hold and this can be shown via definition of derivative, but L'Hospital's Rule does not apply.